# How to massively assign brands to products in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpallimport

I'm importing in woocommerce all the products i have in a csv file with wpallimport. Everything works well. Brands are correctly imported but not related to products. I can manually correlate the brand inside the product page but since they are 2500 products would be nice to be able to set them massively. How can I solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brand is not included *as is* in WooCommerce, so you need to use **products attributes** to handle this information.

When managing your import, open the *WooCommerce Add-On* tab, then the *Attributes* tab. The `Name` attribute will be *Brand*, and the `Values` are the given brands stored in your CSV file (just drag and drop from the right side panel to this field).

It should look like [in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZClKs.jpg).